# TextArea in Facebook home page - unable to locate with selenium locator - Is it jquery or Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selenium

Login with any of our facebook credentials. You will be landed in below page.

**Question:** Do you see "What's on your mind" (or) " continue to post" text area?

I want to locate the text area, enter the text and click post. This is my test case.

I am trying to locate with selenium locators. I have tried with `CSS`, `xpath` but couldn't. I heard this is developed by `jQuery / AJAX`.

**Question:** Can you Pl help me to avoid the challenges and locate this element? If jQuery / AJAX is used, let me know how to locate and resolve the situation?

I have tried with below code snippet and always returns false in console after landed in facebook home page.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

    Object numberOfAjaxConnections = js
            .executeScript("return jQuery.active === 0"); //||window.jQuery != undefined 
    System.out.println(numberOfAjaxConnections);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector is `"div[data-testid='status-attachment-mentions-input']"`. Click that and then the text area pops up and is editable. You should be able to send text to the page at that point.